# Submitting form with select and textfield as disabled and hidden fields. Values not stored properly

Tags: java, struts2

I have a screen where i want the components disabled when i first traverse to the screen(view mode). When i click on Edit button an action is fired and i reload the same screen with the components (cName and cStatus) as editable. Previously, i couldn't retain the values of cID, cName and cStatus when the screen was reloaded so i made 3 hidden fields with the same names. Now i am able to retain the values of all the 3 pages in editable mode(modify mode).

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <s:form name="c" validate="true">
<s:hidden name="cID" />
<s:hidden name="cName" />
<s:hidden name="cStatus" />

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <s:if test="%{mode=='view'}">
            <td><s:submit name="btnEdit" value="Edit" onclick="onEdit()" /></td>
        </s:if>
        <s:elseif test="%{mode=='modify'}">
            <td><s:submit name="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="onSave()" /></td>
        </s:elseif>
        <td><s:submit name="btnBack" value="Back" onclick="onBack()" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<fieldset style="width: 60%"><legend>Details</legend>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td><s:label name="ID" value="ID" /></td>
        <td><s:label name="cID" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><s:label name="Name" value=" Name" /></td>
        <s:if test="%{mode=='view'}">
            <td><s:textfield name="cName" disabled="true" /></td>
        </s:if>
        <s:elseif test="%{mode=='modify'}">
            <td><s:textfield name="cName" id="id2" /></td>
        </s:elseif>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><s:label name="CStatus" value="Status" /></td>
        <s:if test="%{mode=='view'}">
            <td><s:select name="cStatus"
                list="#{'Y':'Active', 'N':'Inactive'}" disabled="true" /></td>
        </s:if>
        <s:elseif test="%{mode=='modify'}">
            <td><s:select name="cStatus"
                list="#{'Y':'Active','N':'Inactive'}" /></td>
        </s:elseif>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
 </s:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now my problem is that,
suppose if i have value "xyz" in cName and "Single" in cStatus.
In modify mode i change the values to "xyza" in cName and "Married" in cStatus and submit the form.
In action class i receive the Value Object set as
cName="xyz, xyza"
cStatus="Single, Married"
instead of
cName="xyza"
cStatus="Married"

Comment: is it ok to define the same name for cName, cStatus to textfield as well as to hidden? I think, this may gives a problem.

Comment: giving the same name to cName and cStatus is giving me problem.

Comment: is it correctly execute now? Because it still contains the same name fields (hidden as well as textfield)

Comment: I think, if you could use <input type=text...> for text field and use hidden as it is, will solve your problem

Comment: Now i added <s:if test="%{mode=='view'}"> statement to jsp i.e. i am using hidden tag only in view mode. Now in modify mode as both textfield and select tags are enabled, Value Object is automatically set, so there is no need to pass hidden values. Its working now.

Comment: add it as an answer and accept it to help others solve their problems

Comment: @Kitri: better use some javascript functionality as suggested by Norman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem i added

```
 <s:if test="%{mode=='view'}">
 <s:hidden name="cName" />
 <s:hidden name="cStatus" />
 </s:if>
```

statement to jsp i.e. i am using hidden tag only in view mode. Now in modify mode as both textfield and select tags are enabled, Value Object is automatically set, so there is no need to pass hidden values. Its working now.

Answer (score 3):

Make this simple change in code:

```
<s:if test="%{mode=='view'}">
     <s:hidden name="cName" />
     <s:hidden name="cStatus" />
</s:if>
```

If you need to compare the values to know if the inputs are changed, then use another variable name to store the hidden values. You may change the code to :

```
     <s:hidden value="cName" name="prevCName"/>
     <s:hidden value="cStatus" name="prevCStatus"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

When I want to do similar things, I use JavaScript to store any modified values into hidden variables. This can be triggered either on the onchange event on the controls, onsumbit on the form or when you exit editing mode. These types of operations are very easy using the Prototype or jQuery JavaScript libraries.

Since you have two text field named cName, if you enable the disabled one, you'll get two results when you submit. You can also give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

You should just simply set your `Edit button` to be an action and post the `read mode` displaying form to the action, so the fields can be obtained and populated.

And yet, add a `onsubmit` javascript event to enable the `disabled` control when clicking the `edit button` so those fields would also be sent.

If you do not want to use javascript, a workaround may be to display the select boxes as text field and set them to `readonly` during `read mode`.